# What is the Erso family’s relationship with the Force?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

There are some interesting but tenuous connections between scenes with the Erso family and the Force, not limited to the following:

- Galen Erso plays a critical role in the construction of the first Death Star, which is powered by kyber crystals-- they are also the power source for lightsabers. I acknowledge the distant potential relationship here, but considering Galen's complicated relationship with the Empire, I think it's reasonable to believe there is a connection here.
- Lyra Erso tells her daughter to "trust the Force" prior to their separation, in addition to giving her a necklace with a crystal that may or may not be a kyber crystal.

What role does the Force play in their lives? What is their relationship with the Force?

Comment: I don't believe using a phrase such as *"trust the force"* is an indication that one is connected to the Force somehow. The rebel alliance used the *"May the Force be with you"* slogan quite often...

Comment: @LcSalazar Yeah, you're right. I suppose I think my perspective forced an assumed relationship on the family.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Lyra might be considered a non-Jedi believer in the Force.**

> Jyn had nursed herself to  sleep, and Lyra could hear Galen and the
> others talking in the main cabin, glad not to be a part of the
> conversation. For her, governments of any stripe would have their
> constituents believe that they were attempting to remove chaos from
> the galaxy, that they were trying to make things perfect, when only
> the Force was perfect. For ordinary beings, life was a constant
> interplay between order and chaos, day and night, light and dark.
>
> **Her reverence for the Force had evolved from an enduring love of
> nature.** Yes, she thought of herself as agile and strong and intuitive,
> but she understood that her skills were a far cry from those
> attributed to the Jedi. **She did, however, embrace the Order’s
> philosophy of generosity, compassion, and peaceful resolution**, and on
> many a far-flung world she had experienced moments in nature that
> could only be described as transcendent. It was certainly possible
> that those peak moments had their basis in belief and emotion, but
> that hardly mattered; even if she wasn’t able to use the Force, she
> could at least feel it, and she was content with that.
>
> <sub>*Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel*</sub>

We’ve seen these before, from some among the Lasat (who call it the Ashla), to the Church of the Force from *The Force Awakens*.

**Galen isn’t much of a believer**, but becomes obsessed with kyber crystals. He sees the Force as simply another aspect of nature.

> “The Force derives from nature,” Galen said somberly. “Against such
> chaos, even the Jedi are capable of accomplishing only so much.”
>
> <sub>*Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel*</sub>

He even hopes that the Force may one day be explained:

> He nodded, as if assessing her words. “I’ll defer to the Order’s sound
> judgment. We’ll investigate with judicious care. But who knows, one
> day we may even get to the root of the Force itself.”
>
> <sub>*Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel*</sub>

That Lyra had a kyber crystal to give to Jyn can easily be attributed to Galen’s access to them during his research, and her own affinity for all things related to the Force.

Comment: that is interesting "even if she wasn’t able to use the Force, she could at least feel it, and she was content with that." that means they changed things and even not force sensitive are now able to feel the force if attuned oO

Comment: @Thomas - Or she believed she could feel it but couldn't. Or she was a little Force- sensitive (everyone has some midi-chlorians, after all, and some people might not quite have enough to do anything but feel the Force).

Answer (score 6):

This is referenced in the [Star Wars: Rogue One - The Ultimate Visual Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Rogue-Ultimate-Visual-x/dp/146545263X). In short, Lyra Erso has developed a spiritual connection to Jedi philosophy and may be a covert Jedi sympathiser.

> Although Lyra has never met a Jedi Knight. she studied their history
>   and philosophies, even when the Galactic Empire frowned upon such
>   research. It is not known if she ever made contact with the rumoured
>   Church of the Force movement reputed to be growing in the shadows of
>   Coruscant, but she did at that time don the scarlet vestments of the
>   sects native to Jedha - One of the last holy outposts of Force
>   knowledge in the Galaxy.

The crystal necklace was indeed a khyber crystal. It has some Aurabesh writing on it, but it doesn't appear to have any meaning when translated into English (*UT?N THN*)

> This small stone - a fragment of khyber crystal from Galen Erso's
>   research - caught Lyra's eye as her family fled Coruscant. She took it
>   to be a good omen and passed it to Jyn, who at the time didn't
>   understand, but knew it was a gift nonetheless.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It seemed clear that the pendant mentioned in *Catalyst* was supposed to be the one Jyn received, but that seems inconsistent with the second quote. I’m having trouble finding a mention of some kyber crystal catching Lyra’s eye, too....

Comment: @Adamant - I've checked. The one in the visual dictionary doesn't have her name on it.

Comment: I think that was a figure of speech.

Comment: Did the crystal necklace have any special Force powers described in The Ultimate Visual Guide or other sources?

Comment: @Essen - No, it's just a shard of khyber crystal.

Comment: @Adamant - What was the pendant mentioned in Catalyst?

Comment: @Lupin - Just a pendant with her name on it. It seems to have been replaced in the story by the kyber shard. It feels like a retcon though.