# What is the locket wore by Jyn Erso in Rogue One made of?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, props

In *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*, we can see Jyn Erso getting a locket from her mother who says,

> Trust The Force.

Here is the picture of that locket.

[image]

She later uses it when they were about to pass through entry at Planet Scarif.

**What is this locket made of?**

Comment: Related, not dupe; [What is the Erso family’s relationship with the Force?
Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147866/what-is-the-erso-family-s-relationship-with-the-force/147869#147869)

Comment: There's a scene in the movie that touches on this, when Jyn first meets Chirrut Îmwe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's made from kyber crystal, according to the film's visual dictionary.

[image]

Comment: I can't see anything written on the locket in the movie, but there is something written on it in this picture.

Comment: @Not - It's written on the back. You only see the front in the film